# PHP Form Variables and POST - HTML Encoded Strings

Tags: php, html, forms

I am not strong on my PHP knowledge, but I have never seen this before.  In a config file, there are a list of options defined in an array like so:

```
$testarray[] = "None";
$testarray[] = "Item 1 with normal text";
$testarray[] = "Item 2&reg; with html encoded string";
$testarray[] = "Item3&reg; with another html encoded string";
```

So now, when the form is generated, it does a simple for each loop to create a list of radio buttons:

```
foreach ( $testarray as $key=>$item){
echo '<div id="padBottom"><input type="radio" name="formItem"';
    if ( $item == $_SESSION['ss']['selection']) echo ' checked="checked"';
    echo ' value="' . $item. '" />' . $item. '</div>';
}
```

So far so good, the form generates like it should.  The part that is not working is the If statement portion.  On the page that this form posts to, it does a simple call to set `$_SESSION['ss']['selection'] = $_POST['formItem'];`  When this happens, the value that goes into session is the actual registered trademark symbol and not `'&reg;'` as I would expect.  As a result, if you select an item with the HTML encoded entity in it, we are not getting a match and your selection appears to be lost. In this example, choosing the first or second option results in the proper radio button being selected - if you choose option 3 or 4, then no selection appears to have been made when you return to this screen.

Addtional info - the charset for this page is UTF-8 if that makes any difference here.

**Things I have tried**

1. htmlspecialchars on the POST variable in the next page: result, nothing, still showing actual symbol.
2. htmlspecialchars on the form value for each radio option: result, I get `&amp;reg;` as part of my value which doesn't display well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some characters (including ampersands) have special meaning in HTML, you have to [represent them as entities](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) if you don't want that special meaning to take effect.

In this case, it is the variable you are inserting into the value attribute that you need to encode.

Comment: thanks for the input.  I knew it had something to do with html encoding, I just hadn't tried the right combination yet.  I tried #1 above and then #2 above with #1 still in place and that didn't work.  But just simply html encoding the value and not again on the post worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It might work better if you used the index of the item, rather than its contents, as the index is just a number in this case:

```
foreach ( $testarray as $key=>$item) {
  echo '<div id="padBottom"><input type="radio" name="formItem"';
  if ( $key == $_SESSION['ss']['selection']) echo ' checked="checked"';
  echo ' value="' . $key .'" />' . $item. '</div>';
}
```

Comment: Yeah i agree, I would much rather use integer keys than string matching, but alas, that is not what was given to me from the last programmer and I am not about to refactor this steaming pile o' code :)